# ant tar task: way to enable "tar append"?

Tags: ant, tar

Goal: use ant to create a *single* tar archive for
any combination of (say) 5 folders (all folders, or any 3 folders
or any 4 folders ...).  I prefer not using temp dirs and the copy command.

This should be simple if the ant tar task supports append.

A search lead me to:

> Setting mode="update" in the compress antlib's tar task should do what is requested.

from: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39617

How do I know if 'antlib' is installed, or how do I
install it.  How does one set mode="update" - which file is chgd?.

--
What is the best way to enable "tar apend" in ant's tar task?

--
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [ant tar task: procedure for enabling "tar append"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245144/ant-tar-task-procedure-for-enabling-tar-append)