# ant tar task: procedure for enabling "tar append"

Tags: ant, tar

Goal: use ant to create a single tar archive for any combination
of (say) 5 folders (all folders, or any 3 folders or any 4 folders
...). I prefer not using temp dirs and the copy command.

This should be simple if the ant tar task supports append.

A search lead me to:

> Setting mode="update" in the compress antlib's tar task should do what is requested.

from: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39617

How do I know if 'antlib' is installed, or how do I install
it. How does one set mode="update" - which file is chgd?.

What is the best way to enable "tar append" in ant's tar task?

GNU tar -r or -u options fail unless the tar file already exists -
any ideas on how to deal w/that in ant?

```
--
```

thanks

PS

The below example is a work around that forks a shell, then checks to
see if the tarfile exists, and runs tar w/append option if it does:

```
<target name="package-blah" description="generate tar file" depends="clean,init">
  <exec executable="sh" >
      <arg value="-xc"/>
      <arg value="
        [[ -f ${tarfile} ]] &amp;&amp; C=r || C=c;
        tar ${C}vf ${tarfile} --exclude '*/.svn' ${src}/main/blah
      "/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

I would prefer not to use the above approach, but it works.

Comment: There was a _very_ [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230389/ant-tar-task-way-to-enable-tar-append) yesterday - is that yours?  If so, perhaps that one can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Two items are needed to use the Compress Antlib:

- The Compress Antlib itself, which can be found [here](http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/compress/).
  *If you already have this it will probably be named **ant-compress-1.0.jar**.*
- Apache Commons Compress, which can be found [here](http://commons.apache.org/compress/).
  *If you have this, it is likely to be called **commons-compress-1.2.jar**.*

You could choose to install these with your Ant installation, but perhaps its neater to include them with your build.

Here's an example Ant buildfile that uses the two downloads, with them placed in a directory named `external` under the basedir for the build.  This creates `my.tar` using files in directory `dir_one` then updates that tar with files added from `dir_two`.

```
<project basedir="." xmlns:compress="antlib:org.apache.ant.compress">

<taskdef uri="antlib:org.apache.ant.compress"
            resource="org/apache/ant/compress/antlib.xml"
            classpath="external/ant-compress-1.0.jar:external/commons-compress-1.2.jar"/>

<delete file="my.tar" />

<compress:tar dest="my.tar" mode="update">
   <fileset dir="dir_one" includes="*.txt" />
</compress:tar>

<compress:tar dest="my.tar" mode="update">
   <fileset dir="dir_two" includes="*.txt" />
</compress:tar>

</project>
```

Note the use of a namespace to disambiguate with the standard Ant `tar` task.  The `taskdef` is needed to make Ant aware of the Antlib.

Care should be taken when merging this way - strange things may appear to happen if files with the same name are merged.  Note that behind the scenes, Commons Compress is creating a temporary copy of the archive anyway, so this doesn't avoid that, it just does it for you.

If you want to explore further options for the [tar task](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/antlibs/compress/trunk/src/main/org/apache/ant/compress/taskdefs/Tar.java) see the superclass [ArchiveBase](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/antlibs/compress/trunk/src/main/org/apache/ant/compress/taskdefs/ArchiveBase.java).

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply - thank you very much!  I need to set aside some time to
try this, after that I will post my results.
--
Tom

Comment: Your example suggests that the compress:tar task may create non compressed tar files.  I need to create non compressed / ordinary tar archives; pls respond if compress:tar can not do so.  Thanks again!

Comment: When I tested it the tar produced was *not* compressed, and was readable using the unix tar command.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than updating an existing archive, why don't you create the archive with multiple source folders in the first place?

```
<tar destfile="${target}/mytar.tar">
    <tarfileset dir="srcdir1">
        <include name="**/*" />
        <exclude name="**/*.sh" />
    </tarfileset>
    <tarfileset dir="srcdir2">
        <include name="**/*.sh" />
    </tarfileset>
    <tarfileset dir="srcdir3">
        <include name="**/*" />
    </tarfileset>
</tar>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

With the append approach you can create a separate target
for each folder;  then from the commandline one can specify *any* combination
of folder targets, and end up w/a single tar archive.